# Haskell calculate time of function performing

Tags: haskell, benchmarking

i tried to code to calculate time that a function costs

```
list <- buildlist 10000 10000    
starttime <- getClockTime
let sortedlist = quicksort list
endtime <- getClockTime
let difftime = diffClockTimes endtime starttime
```

*function buildlist:*

```
buildlist :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
buildlist n m = do
    seed <- getStdGen
    let l = randomRs (0, m) seed
    let list = take n l
    return list
```

*function quicksort:*

```
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let head = [a|a<-xs,a<=x]
        tail = [a|a<-xs,a>x]
    in quicksort head ++ [x] ++ quicksort tail
```

**first question:** when i output the difftime, it is always zero no matter how long the list is.

**second one:** i wonder what ">>=" in the code from [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/systems-programming-in-haskell.html) means.

```
getClockTime >>= (\(TOD sec _) -> return sec)
```

**third:** i write this to get **tdSec** and **tdPicosec** from a **TimeDiff** variable.
is there any easier way?

```
time <-(\(TimeDiff _ _ _ _ _ s ps) -> return [ ( \a -> fromIntegral a :: Double ) s , ( \a -> fromIntegral a :: Double ) ps ] ) difftime
```

Comment: What is the value of `list`?

Comment: In the first bit of code, it's not actually sorting the list because the value of `sortedList` is never used. Why did you expect it to report a non-zero time?

Comment: Also, please don't ask multiple unrelated things in a single question.

Comment: question has been edited @Code-Guru

Comment: because i want to know how long it takes for the quicksort function@C.A.McCann

Comment: sorry,i am new here and this is my second question.i wont do this any more.@C.A.McCann

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Question 1:

Your code does not sort the list!  It simply defines the name `sortedlist` as being `quicksort list` but this wont be computed until the value is actually needed.  That is lazy evaluation.  We do not do extra work in this language.

Since benchmarks are extra useless work (that is the point), this makes benchmarking hard.

Your choices

- Use `seq`.  `seq` has type `a -> b -> b` and has the behavior of evaluating its first argument to what is called "weak head normal form".  Here since you want to force the entire list you might want to use `deepseq`
- Use a proper benchmarking package like [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) (prefered and easier)

### Question 2:

`>>=` is the monadic bind operator.  Here it takes an `IO` action of type `IO a` and a function `a -> IO b` and combines them together to make a new action of type `IO b`.  This does the same thing as do notation.  `foo >>= \x -> expr` is the same thing as

```
 do x <- foo
    expr
```

and in fact, `do` notation is just syntactic sugar for `>>=`

I'm not sure what is being asked in question 3--perhaps it should get its own Stackoverflow question.

Comment: For question three: `get_s_ps td = (tdSec td, tdPicoSec td)`  That is, just use the field accessors, which [you can see as part of the definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/old-time/latest/doc/html/System-Time.html#v:TimeDiff) of the `TimeDiff` type.

Answer (score 4):

`difftime` is always zero, because Haskell's lazy evaluation order has completely optimized away the actual sort.  Nothing in your program accesses `sortedlist`, so it's never even computed.

As stated in another answer, you can force your program to compute `sortedlist` with a somewhat magical function called `deepseq` from `Control.Deepseq`.  `deepseq v` is equivalent to `id`, except that it has the side-effect of forcing `v` to be fully evaluated.

```
starttime <- getClockTime
let sortedlist = quicksort list
endtime <- deepseq sortedlist getClockTime
```

As for your second question, yes, there's an easier way to access the fields of a `TimeDiff`.  The field names in `Data` declaration second as getter functions.  So, `tdSec td` gets the seconds of `td` and `tdPicosec td` gets the picoseconds.

Comment: this benchmarks how long it takes to print.  That may actually be far longer than the task of actually sorting.

Comment: That's quite true, if the list isn't sufficiently large.  I was hoping to avoid bringing up `seq` or `deepseq`, since they're a whole new can of worms.

Answer (score 3):

For measuring the evaluation time of pure functions, you might be interested in my `Chronograph` package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chronograph

Here's a short example of how to use it:

```
Prelude Data.Chronograph> :m Data.Chronograph Data.List
Prelude Data.Chronograph Data.List> let theList = reverse [1..1000]
Prelude Data.Chronograph Data.List> sum theList 
500500
Prelude Data.Chronograph Data.List> let timed = chronoNF (sort theList)
Prelude Data.Chronograph Data.List> measure timed
0.000062s
Prelude Data.Chronograph Data.List> head $ val timed
1
```

A few points:

- I evaluate the sum of the original `theList` to force its construction and reversal.  If it's not forced here, the cost of construction will be attributed to the evaluation of the expression passed into `chronoNF`
- `chronoNF` evaluates using the same strategy as `deepseq` as some other answers discuss.  chronograph provides other functions for different evaluation strategies.  For example, we could evaluate to weak head normal form, which wouldn't actually fully sort the list.

chronograph can also measure `IO` expressions, but those are typically much simpler to deal with than non-IO expressions.