# Why Haskell function execution time measurment differs from ghc timings?

Tags: performance, haskell, time

I want to measure time which Haskell spent to execute some function and use TimeIt package(also i tried [these](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Timing_computations) recommendations). But showed time differs from actual time application spent (I've ran application with +RTS -sstderr option):

```
CPU time:   4.85s
...  
  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.98s  ( 61.69s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.22s  (  0.19s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.20s  ( 61.89s elapsed)
```

Application source:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LBS
import System.Environment
import Data.Char
import Data.Int
import System.TimeIt

readChunks :: Int64 -> LBS.ByteString -> Int64
readChunks size str 
                            | LBS.null str = 0
                            | otherwise = let (chunk, rest) = LBS.splitAt size str
                                                 in do
                                                        let len = LBS.length chunk
                                                        len `seq` len + readChunks size rest



processFile :: String -> IO()
processFile name = do
    putStrLn name
    content <- LBS.readFile name
    let 
        (recNumStr, rest) = LBS.span (not.isControl) content
        recNum = LBS.readInt recNumStr
    case recNum of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "can't parse"
        Just (value, rest) -> print (value)
    let chunkSize = 100*1024*1024   

    timeIt $ print (readChunks chunkSize rest)
```

**UPDATE:** I've found that [Chronograph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chronograph) package shows right execution time (information taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050917/haskell-calculate-time-of-function-performing)).

Answer (score 1):

Well you are doing significant work that isn't being timed - it seems reasonable that this work makes up the difference, namely:

```
putStrLn name
content <- LBS.readFile name
let 
    (recNumStr, rest) = LBS.span (not.isControl) content
    recNum = LBS.readInt recNumStr
case recNum of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "can't parse"
    Just (value, rest) -> print (value)
```

If you time that as well then you'll probably find most the difference.  Also note there are other operations before you even enter `main` (which is true even for C programs).

Comment: I've tried without this part of the code but time didn't changed, I think, because of small length of the first line. Also time measured with ghc or external timer had linear dependency with the size of the input file.